# Why can not get body field in response of Microsoft Graph API for listing messages?

Tags: python, email, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, outlook-restapi

I want to read certain email messages and filter them. I am using Microsoft Graph API to query the office 365 mail box as below. I also added API permission "Mail.ReadBasic.All" for getting mails from application.

```
graph_api_endpoint = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xyz@outlook.com/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$select=body'

# Function to get inbox messages
def get_inbox_messages(access_token):
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Prefer': 'outlook.body-content-type="text"',
    }

    response = requests.get(graph_api_endpoint, headers=headers)
    print('get_inbox_messages response:', response)
    return response.json().get('value', [])


# MSAL ConfidentialClientApplication
app = ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id,
    authority=authority,
    client_credential=client_secret,
)



token_response = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=[scope])
# Access token
access_token = token_response['access_token']
print(f"Access Token: {access_token}")

if access_token:
   inbox_messages = get_inbox_messages(access_token)
   print('Inbox Messages:', inbox_messages)
else:
   print('Failed to obtain access token')
```

But inbox_messages doesn't contain body fields. Its value is like this.

```
[{'@odata.etag': 'W/"CQAAABYAAAB3N5CnvFQSSqeWD3xLEpaUAACbgpYA"', 'id': 'AAMkAGYyMzUwZDAxLTJkNmItNGJjYi1iNThkLTcxMWU2MzIxMjg2ZgBGAAAAAAAKfqhNGZ8HSr-8OzkXZKcQBwB3N5CnvFQSSqeWD3xLEpaUAAAAAAEMAAB3N5CnvFQSSqeWD3xLEpaUAACb9YkJAAA='}, {'@odata.etag': 'W/"CQAAABYAAAB3N5CnvFQSSqeWD3xLEpaUAACbgpAa"', 'id': 'AAMkAGYyMzUwZDAxLTJkNmItNGJjYi1iNThkLTcxMWU2MzIxMjg2ZgBGAAAAAAAKfqhNGZ8HSr-8OzkXZKcQBwB3N5CnvFQSSqeWD3xLEpaUAAAAAAEMAAB3N5CnvFQSSqeWD3xLEpaUAACb9YkIAAA='}, {'@odata.etag': 'W/"CQAAABYAAAB3N5CnvFQSSqeWD3xLEpaUAACazuV6"', 'id': 'AAMkAGYyMzUwZDAxLTJkNmItNGJjYi1iNThkLTcxMWU2MzIxMjg2ZgBGAAAAAAAKfqhNGZ8HSr-8OzkXZKcQBwB3N5CnvFQSSqeWD3xLEpaUAAAAAAEMAAB3N5CnvFQSSqeWD3xLEpaUAACbQPdBAAA='}, {'@odata.etag': 'W/"CQAAABYAAAB3N5CnvFQSSqeWD3xLEpaUAACazuV4"', 'id': 'AAMkAGYyMzUwZDAxLTJkNmItNGJjYi1iNThkLTcxMWU2MzIxMjg2ZgBGAAAAAAAKfqhNGZ8HSr-8OzkXZKcQBwB3N5CnvFQSSqeWD3xLEpaUAAAAAAEMAAB3N5CnvFQSSqeWD3xLEpaUAACbQPdAAAA='}, {'@odata.etag': 'W/"CQAAABYAAAB3N5CnvFQSSqeWD3xLEpaUAACazuVn"', 'id': 'AAMkAGYyMzUwZDAxLTJkNmItNGJjYi1iNThkLTcxMWU2MzIxMjg2ZgBGAAAAAAAKfqhNGZ8HSr-8OzkXZKcQBwB3N5CnvFQSSqeWD3xLEpaUAAAAAAEMAAB3N5CnvFQSSqeWD3xLEpaUAACbQPc-AAA='}, {'@odata.etag': 'W/"CQAAABYAAAB3N5CnvFQSSqeWD3xLEpaUAACazuVg"', 'id': 'AAMkAGYyMzUwZDAxLTJkNmItNGJjYi1iNThkLTcxMWU2MzIxMjg2ZgBGAAAAAAAKfqhNGZ8HSr-8OzkXZKcQBwB3N5CnvFQSSqeWD3xLEpaUAAAAAAEMAAB3N5CnvFQSSqeWD3xLEpaUAACbQPc_AAA='}]
```

Please help me to get body in html format or text format.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior can be cause by the permission `Mail.ReadBasic.All`.

With [this permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#mailreadbasicall) the application cannot read `body`, `previewBody`, `attachments` and any extended properties.

To be able to read body, you need to grant higher privileged application permission `Mail.Read`.

Comment: Thanks, @user2250152.
I could get mail body after adding permission "Mail.Read".